# CodeIgniter: принять post-запрос

Tags: фреймворк, php, codeigniter

Всем привет! Начал изучать фреймворк CodeIgniter, и у меня возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Как принять post-запрос?
2. У меня чпу состоит так: есть файл класса, который я вызываю, это user, затем идут функции:

   public function registration()
   и

   public function auth()

в URL это выглядит так: http://site.ru/user/registration/ или /user/auth/, так вот, как сделать так, чтобы при вызове просто user меня перекидывало на register?
3) Где изменить ошибку 404? Где они вообще хранятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке `config` есть файл `routes.php`, можно там сделать переадресацию. Hапример:

```
$route['user']='user/registration';
```

Что касается приема POST-запроса, то в CI это делается так:

```
$this->input->post('имя POST элемента');
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть здесь: [CodeIgniter, руководство пользователя к версии 1.6.1](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/input.html)